# React Native/Firebase can't find variable "Ref"

Tags: variables, firebase, react-native, server

**Problem:**
I am trying to create a simple app where users can post stuff to the internet using React Native and Firebase. When I added the code to upload the variable, "postInput" to firebase, I got the error "Can't find variable: Ref." I never defined ref as a variable, but I think it was supposed to automatically work when I imported * from firebase. I don't know why this is and I would love some help.

**Error:**
Can't find variable: ref.

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TextInput, ScrollView, TouchableHighlight, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Font } from 'expo';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

var fontLoaded = false;

var postRef = ref.child("posts");

var newPostRef = postsRef.push();

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "__API_KEY__",
  authDomain: "candidtwo.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://candidtwo.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "candidtwo.appspot.com",
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    fontLoaded: false,
  };



  componentDidMount() {
      Expo.Font.loadAsync({
        'JosefinSans-Regular.ttf': require('./JosefinSans-Regular.ttf'),
      });
 }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { postInput: ""}
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <View style={{width: 1, height: 30, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
          <Button
            onPress={() => this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })}
            title="Press Me To Load the App After 15 Seconds!"
            color="#fe8200"
            accessibilityLabel="Wait 15 seconds and then press me to load the font!"
          />
        </View>


        {this.state.fontLoaded ? (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular', fontSize: 16 }}>
                Whats on your mind? Create a post!
            </Text>  

            <TextInput
                 style={{height:40, width: 320, borderColor: '#303030', borderWidth: 1}}
                 onChangeText={(postInput)=>this.setState({postInput})}
                 value={this.state.postInput}    
             />


    <Button
      onPress={() => {
        newPostRef.set({ content:this.state.postInput });
        this.setState({ postInput: "Your post was succsesfully uploaded! :)" })    
      }}               
      title="                              +                              "
      color="#fe8200"
    />

            <ScrollView>
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 350, height: 250, backgroundColor: '#1daff1',  alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center',    borderRadius: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight:10}} >
         <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular', fontSize: 18, color: '#ffffff', textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    Why do android phones have higher inital quality than apple phones, but apple phones have a more consistent amount of quality throughout their years?
                </Text>
            </View>
               <View style={{width: 350, height: 40, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: '#147aa8', flexDirection: 'row',paddingLeft:5}} >
            <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/unlove.png')} />
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular', fontSize: 18, color: '#ffffff'}}>
                    3
                    </Text>
            <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/undislike.png')} />
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular', fontSize: 18, color: '#ffffff'}}>
                    1
                    </Text>
            <Image source={require('./CandidtwoImages/comments.png')} />
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'JosefinSans-Regular', fontSize: 18, color: '#ffffff'}}>
                    8
                    </Text>
        </View>
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 35, height: 25, backgroundColor: '#147c41', borderRadius: 10}} />
               <View style={{width: 35, height: 4, backgroundColor: '#0f582d', borderRadius: 10}} />
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 35, height: 25, backgroundColor: '#9dcd46', borderRadius: 10}} />
               <View style={{width: 35, height: 4, backgroundColor: '#6c8f31', borderRadius: 10}} />
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
           <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />
               <View style={{width: 35, height: 25, backgroundColor: '#d3832e', borderRadius: 10}} />
               <View style={{width: 35, height: 4, backgroundColor: '#935b1e', borderRadius: 10}} />
               <View style={{width: 1, height: 6, backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8'}} />

             </ScrollView>
          </View>) : (null) }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e8e8e8',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access a `ref` variable that does not exist. 
By importing `firebase` at the top of your file you have access to the
`firebase` variable which you can use like this :

```
var postRef = firebase.database().ref('posts')
```

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in your question that you imported firebase as :
 imported * from firebase

but in your code you mentioned like this : 
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

either you have to use  firebase.database().ref('posts') or remove as firebase and use database().ref('posts') in your code.Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 'firebase' is a RN package. I believe you are using a npm module which won't work. There is an specific firebase module for RN: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mixed things up a bit. You need to first initialize firebase then use `ref` from `database`.

**Example**

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "__API_KEY__",
  authDomain: "someapp.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://someapp.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "someapp.appspot.com",
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const Database = firebaseApp.database();

var postRef = Database.ref().child("posts");
```